# Does the Python built-in library have an incrementable counter?

Tags: python

Is there anything like this in the Python built-in library:

```py
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.val = start

    def consume(self):
        val = self.val
        self.val += 1
        return val
```

I see this as much safer way of implementing code where a counter needs to be used and then immediately incremented on the next line. Kind of like using `i++` in other languages. But I'm trying to avoid clogging up my library with definitions like this if there's an inbuilt method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically reimplemented `itertools.count`, with `consume` standing in for `__next__`. (`__next__` is not typically called directly, but by passing the instance of `count` to the `next` function.)

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count()
>>> next(c)
0
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(c)
2
```